# Jquery fancybox pop-up to show in the middle of the screen

Tags: jquery, ios, css, facebook, ipad

I am creating a Facebook app where there is a fancy-box pop-up appearing when I click on a button , for web the pop-up is opening at the middle of the display(monitor) but when I check it in Ipad it comes at the middle of the app which is not the middle of the screen of the ipad .(As the button is in the header section  and I have long content and images in the app ie the app page is long in height ).

I have tried to calculate the top and reassign the positions but it doesn't working in case of ipad.

Fancybox version is 2.1.5

Any help regarding this will be appreciable.

Comment: Are you checking it on ipad portrait view? Also your web is responsive?

Comment: This is happening in portrait view as well in landscape view also

Comment: which fancybox version are you using?

Comment: Fancybox version  is 2.15 .

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the autoCenter property to true.

**Example 1:**

```
$("#single_1").fancybox({
      autoCenter: true,
      ...
  });
```

If that doesn't work, try repositioning the fancybox to the available screen width/height.

**Example 2:**

```
$.fancybox.reposition()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have used autoCenter: true, It works for web but not for ipad and how do I implement $.fancybox.reposition() this ..

Comment: https://apps.facebook.com/myspalumnisg/#_=_ this is the app and when you click on "Pen your wishes & win " the popup will open